# Not able to understand conditional type use case typescript

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I am trying to understand how conditional types in typescript can be helpful in a real use case hence I contrived an example to make sure I understood it correctly, here is the example

```
/**
 * I used these inherited classes because I thought that type for enum member cannot be matched,
 * but I was wrong so revert back to enum
 */
// abstract class ResultType {}

// class ErrorType extends ResultType {}

// class SuccessType extends ResultType{}

// Type to infer if final response is going to be ErrorResult or SuccessResult
enum ResultType {
    ERROR = "Error",
    SUCCESS = "Success"
}

// Wants to return ErrorResult for error case from takeAction according to condition
type ErrorResult = { resultType: ResultType.ERROR; value: string; }

// Wants to return SuccessResult for success case with any object to be consumed by caller
type SuccessResult<Value> = { resultType: ResultType.SUCCESS; value: Value; }

// Need to support union type of error & success results
type Result = ErrorResult | SuccessResult<unknown> 

type ExtractResponseType<ActionReturnType extends Result, SuccessResponseType = undefined>
  = ActionReturnType['resultType'] extends ResultType.ERROR ? ErrorResult : SuccessResult<SuccessResponseType>

interface SomeObj {
  message: string;
  code: number;
}

function takeAction<T>(val: number) {
  let retVal;
  if (val == 1) {
    retVal = { resultType : ResultType.ERROR, value: 'Value 1 is not acceptable' } as ErrorResult
    type X = ExtractResponseType<typeof retVal>
    return retVal as X
  }

  retVal = { resultType: ResultType.SUCCESS, value: { message: 'I am happy you have passed this value', code: val } } as SuccessResult<T>
  type X = ExtractResponseType<typeof retVal, T>
  return retVal as X
}

// wants type for firstValue to be inferred as ErrorResult
let firstValue = takeAction<SomeObj>(1)
console.log(firstValue)

// wants type for secondValue to be inferred as SuccessResult<SomeObj>
let secondValue = takeAction<SomeObj>(2)
console.log(secondValue)
```

Now, my expectation was that it would show the type `ErrorResult` for `firstValue` and `SuccessResult<SomeObj>` for `secondVal` but it shows `ErrorResult` for both line. So either it is not clear to me if it is possible at all or I am making some mistake in my example and hence it might not be working.

May someone be able to explain what I am doing wrong here?

FYI, I tried this on [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#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-X643m62xrGAMHZoqMVr0gwdDVogIZhsI2aUI4nI8vyECssIcq5jqDAwVq2AkmI9QFChfICphnoAEz+kAA) with version 4.8.2

*Edit*: From the first draft of the question, it was not clear what I want to achieve here, so I am adding it here.

Basically, I am trying to implement pattern matching on structurally similar objects and want my function to return the exact type when some particular condition is met or can implement it somehow on caller side to infer exact type returned. Right now function is returning union type of `ErrorResult` & `SuccessResult`. Something similar like kotlin, rust etc have.

Comment: Maybe start with a more minimal example? There is several things that are strange or doesn't make sense here, it's hard to know what were your intentions exactly.

Comment: Similar to if statements, conditional types allow you to "change" the type of something if a condition is met. Normally, the condition is checking if a generic type extends (is assignable to) another type.

Comment: [The documentation page also has an example...](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html)

Comment: Hi, @Blackhole I have made some edits, please have a look if it is still unclear, thanks.

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ5YZm) what you wanted? Your original code's conditional had nothing to do with the `value` parameter, so the return type did not change based on the `value` parameter.

Comment: Hi @caTS Yes, something like this, but as I said earlier was a little contrived example, in actual it should not depend on input to the function, basically I want if caller is getting union type, it should be able to exact match the actual value being returned without checking type but I think that may not be possible.

Comment: Nope, that's not how conditionals work. How is the compiler supposed to work out the correct conditional return type for a function given only the possible return values? Return types define what the function can return in the body, not the other way around.